# Integer to store color in C, endian dependent

Tags: c, colors, endianness

I have a question about endianness, I like to store my colors in HTML format (RGB like #aabbcc).

I always use 0xaabbcc in my code to store the color, and then to extract the red, green and blue colors I apply masks like this:

```
int color = 0xaabbcc;
int r = color & 0xff0000;
int g = color & 0x00ff00;
int b = color & 0x0000ff;
```

This works well, but I have not tested under a big endian machine, will the result be the same?

I must see that SDL checks the endian for creating surfaces as in the example of man SDL_CreateRGBSurface:

```
#if SDL_BYTEORDER == SDL_BIG_ENDIAN
   rmask = 0xff000000;
   gmask = 0x00ff0000;
   bmask = 0x0000ff00;
   amask = 0x000000ff;
#else
   rmask = 0x000000ff;
   gmask = 0x0000ff00;
   bmask = 0x00ff0000;
   amask = 0xff000000;
#endif

   surface = SDL_CreateRGBSurface(SDL_SWSURFACE, width, height, 32,
                                  rmask, gmask, bmask, amask);
```

Comment: I think your concept is wrong. Why not store it as an unsigned char array? Each byte would be represented by a char (assuming this goes from 0 to 255) and then you can read out each R, G, B segment easily without all of this bit twiddling. Heck, if you wrote this to a file then read it back in as std::string, the values could be hexadecimal, decimal, or octal as long as you use strtol() on the individual values, then set it in your RGB array.

Comment: The weird one is going to be little endian, where you'll see `ccbbaa00` in your hex dumps instead of `00aabbcc` (big endian).  Of course, nobody really cares about how nice things look in hex dumps.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Bitmasks are independent of endianness. The only place where endianness would be an issue would be if you were casting it to a byte array (or, in c, a `char *`), in which case the endianness would matter.

Also ensure that `sizeof(int) > 3` before using this code!

Comment: Technically, you want to know that `sizeof(int) * CHAR_BIT >= 24`, but I think in 2012 we can forgive people for writing C code that assumes that int is 32 bits.

Comment: Or `#include <stdint.h>` and use the `uint32_t` datatype.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you are dealing with the actual individual bits, endianness does not matter. You run into issues when dealing with the numeric values that the bits represent. You are simply setting a value, and then using a mask to read it back, so you should not have any problems.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're serializing the data in some way (saving to disk, sending over a network link) or accessing it as something other than an integer (as in Richard J. Ross III's answer mentioning a `char *`), it doesn't matter.  Your variables and your masks have the same byte order.